# How to post on my own Facebook page using Facebook SDK?

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-sdk-3.1

I have created a Facebook App to publish posts from my website to Facebook page.

When I submitted the App for review they rejected to give permissions for `publish_pages`.

These are notes from reviewer:

> Your app doesn't need to submit for manage_pages or publish_pages to
>   post to Pages or blogs that you admin. As an app admin, you can
>   already access these permissions and post to your own timeline, pages
>   and groups.

But the question is how can I access `manage_pages` or `publish_pages` permissions?

If the App is not in **Live Mode**, I can request these permissions from the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), but in this case the published posts are visible only by me.

If the App is in **Live Mode** I can not request these permissions.

How can I get `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` in **Live Mode** as an Admin?

Is this [message from Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/examples#screencast) correct?

> You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or
>   by a reduced number of people. Any account listed in the Roles tab in
>   your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can access
>   all permissions and generate a user or page access token.

Comment: I think the reviewer is wrong here. Try and submit again, and explicitly explain that you need to submit, because otherwise you can not grant the necessary permissions when the app is live.

Comment: @misorude how to understend this message: You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or by a reduced number of people. Any account listed in the Roles tab in your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can access all permissions and generate a user or page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/examples#screencast

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is an update for 2020.
When I'm trying to post to my own page, I have the same problem, only admins and testers can see the posts.

I found this in the docs which would explain things:
**"Any data generated while in development mode can only be seen by users who have a role on your app. However, once you switch your app to live mode, that data will be visible to anyone who is able to use your app."**

More on dev mode here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps#development-mode

An app review for something I could do manually seems like overkill to me. Especially when my requested permission (pages_manage_posts) won't give me access to other users data. But I guess the current process is better than what they had before, all user data up for grabs for everyone.

Comment: Well, if you read this additional info about the pages_manage_posts permissions, including having to sign contracts etc... you really just want to give up on this auto-posting thing... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_manage_posts